# How often do people mistype their password?

Tags: login

Has anyone done any studies or gathered data on how often people typically mistype their password? What is a normal rate of fat-fingering, forgetting password, etc.?

Comment: I would imagine that if CAPS-LOCK is enabled then the data would be skewed to a higher percentage for that login instance. What UX problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm honestly not too sure if this is a UX question. Because I don't see a UX question here.

Comment: @Majo0od I disagree. Knowledge of how often user makes error is an important factor in UX design. How can we make the login process simpler without compromising security is what I read into this question. (+1)

Comment: That is true, but that's not what he's asking. He's just asking how often a password is mistyped. 

How to make the login process easier has been discussed before (not sure about here, but it has on another places)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could refer on this question on security StackExchange for some statistics:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6682/passwords-any-statistics-on-user-behavior

You may also go here at https://passwordresearch.com to check some helpful password statistics.